# Detect when text is selected iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, selection

How can I tell when text is selected in a UITextView? I'm assuming I need to something with NSNotifcationCenter. This is a simple question and SO won't let me post this question without meeting their minimum required characters, so this is a filler.

Comment: UITextViewDelegate...

Comment: If your question doesn't meet minimum required characters maybe you shouldn't have asked in the first place. Did you check the object's delegate methods?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a lazy question which shows no evidence of an attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
   UITextRange *selectedRange = [textView selectedTextRange];
   NSString *selectedText = [textView textInRange:selectedRange];
}
```

Comment: Please mark answer if its Okay.